# Unable to forward messages from outlook to gmail

Tags: powershell, exchange, outlook, exchangeonline

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/user-mailboxes/email-forwarding?view=exchserver-2019

I referred the above tutorial to setup email forwarding in exchange. It was working fine when I configured email forwarding from EAC. But it was to another user in the same domain.

But when I tried to forward the mails to a gmail account using powershell, even though the code executed successfully mails are not forwarded to the target gmail account and whenever i send mails to the configured outlook mail I receive the following error : "Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:". But the mail gets delivered.

The powershell code i used is this :

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity "cliff" -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ForwardingSMTPAddress "<recipient>@gmail.com"
```

Comment: the  error message gives you the failed adress ? You should edit the question to replace the gmail.com adress to something generic like <myrecipient>@gmail.com to avoid spam

Comment: @Brice yes.the error message gives the outlook address. but mail gets delivered at that address. However it does not get forwarded to the gmail account.

Comment: What happens if you send emails directly to the gmail mailbox? Are there any filters which were created to block emails in the "Filters and Blocked Addresses" gmail setting.

Comment: Hi, it's been a long time, is there any update? If the issue has been fixed, you could mark the best answer. Have a good day:)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you send emails directly to the gmail mailbox? Are there any filters which were created to block emails in the "**Filters and Blocked Addresses**" gmail setting.

Comment: When I send mails directly to gmail it gives me an error : " Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it". But in the "Filters and Blocked Addresses" in gmail I have only blocked Paytm and nothing else.

Comment: Did you get one code in the bounce message?(Just like "5.7.0" in the message "Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it.
Remote Server returned '554 5.7.0...'").

At the same time, try to forward the emails to another mailbox which is not a gmail one and see if the same issue happens.

Comment: I tried your suggestion.I got the same error when i tried to send mail to a different domain. The error is this: "Remote Server returned '550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP. "

Comment: Visit the URL "https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx" to see if your server IP or domain was added in the blacklist. Besides, the similar thread may be helpful to you: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/15555225?hl=en

Comment: Hi, it's been a long time, is there any update? If the above methods are helpful to you, you could mark the best answer to help people who have the same problem. Have a nice day:)